# Comparing floating point with another number

Tags: perl, floating-point

How to check if one floating point number is bigger than another number in Perl?

i.e: 100.4 > 90

I tried to work with `use POSIX`, rounding the 100.4 to 101.0 and converting both of them with int, but Perl still thinks that my 100.4 is smaller than my 90.

Edit: The bug was somewhere else. The privious code returned me sometimes true and sometimes false.

Comment: Perl did not do something wrong, you did. Show the code which produces the behaviour you describe and we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: cannot reproduce: `perl -E'say 0+(100.4 > 90)'` – `1` and `perl -MPOSIX=ceil -E'say 0+( ceil(100.4) > 90 )'` – `1` and `perl -MPOSIX=ceil -E'say 0+( int(ceil(100.4)) > int(90) )'` – still `1`.

Comment: `100.4 lt 90` is true. `100.4 < 90` is not. The former is a string comparison, the latter a numerical comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Perl doesn't 'think' that, and that's easy to check:

```
print 100.4 > 90 ? 'Greater' : 'Lesser'; # Greater
```

My (wild) guess is that you've tried to sort an array of floats, and got 100.4 standing before 90. For example, like this:

```
my @floats = (100.4, 50, 9);
print $_, "\n" for sort @floats; 
# 100.4
# 50
# 9
```

The catch is that by default Perl uses string comparison in `sort`. So both 100.4 and 90 are cast to string first, and `'100.4'` is indeed lesser than `'9'`, because `'1'` is lesser than `'9'` (strings are compared char-by-char).

The solution is simple: override the sorting routine when dealing with numbers.

```
print $_, "\n" for sort { $a <=> $b } @floats; 
# 9
# 50
# 100.4
```

Comment: That's a good guess, I was thinking it was either some sort of obscured stringification e.g. `"x100.4" < 90` or a using `,` instead of `.`, `if (100,4 > 90)`.. both of which will work silently if warnings is off.